# Create Office Excel Doc with Linq to XML, XMLNS, XDeclaration, Cell formatting (works)

Tags: c#, .net, excel, linq-to-xml, ms-office

I need to replicate this XML in C# and Linq to XML. I dont want any dependencies to other libraries other than the normal .NET ones. The XML is shown below.

**Problem:** I can't figure out how to print these two lines:

```
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Data ss:Type="String">name</Data>
```

Full XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
  xmlns:x2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/excel/2003/xml"
  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
  xmlns:c="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:component:spreadsheet">
    <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"></OfficeDocumentSettings>
    <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"></ExcelWorkbook>
    <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet 1">
        <Table>
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">name</Data>
                    </Cell>
                                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">status</Data>
                </Cell>
                           </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Niike2</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Enabled</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
        </Table>
    </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Code:

```
XNamespace ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", string.Empty),
        new XComment(String.Format("Exported: {0}", DateTime.Now)),
        new XElement(ns + "Workbook",
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "x", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"),
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "x2", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/excel/2003/xml"),
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"),
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "html", "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"),
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "c", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:component:spreadsheet"),
            new XElement(ns + "Worksheet",
            new XElement(ns + "Table",
                new XElement(ns + "Row",
                    new XElement(ns + "Cell", "name")
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second line with <? .... ?> is called a Processing Instruction.  The rest is just manipulating namespaces.

```
XNamespace ss = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
XNamespace x = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel";
XNamespace x2 = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/excel/2003/xml";
XNamespace o = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office";
XNamespace html = "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40";
XNamespace c = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:component:spreadsheet";

XDocument doc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", string.Empty),
        new XComment(String.Format("Exported: {0}", DateTime.Now)),
        new XProcessingInstruction("mso-application", "progid=\"Excel.Sheet\""),        
        new XElement("Workbook",            
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "x", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"),
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "x2", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/excel/2003/xml"),
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ss", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"),
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"),
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "html", "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"),
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "c", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:component:spreadsheet"),
            new XElement("Worksheet", new XAttribute(ss + "Name", "Sheet 1"),               
                new XElement("Table",
                    new XElement("Row",
                        new XElement("Cell",
                            new XElement("Data", new XAttribute(ss + "Type", "String"),"status"))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: @John Saunders - Can you explain that a bit more? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387069.aspx

Comment: @TheJuice: that might matter if he needed to control the prefixes. He almost certainly does not-he needs the namespaces to be correct, not the prefixes. Your example only works because all elements are in the default namespace: did you realize that?

Comment: @John Saunders - He said he needed to "replicate this XML" which means "Make an exact copy of; reproduce".  In his code he was making the namespace prefixes match the desired XML so I left that in there since it is correct.  My code showed how to add the Processing Instruction and add a namespace to his attributes.  Maybe you should also post an answer instead of just down-voting mine.

Comment: @TheJuice: I would if I had time. I don't. BTW, most people who think they have to replicate XML exactly don't understand XML namespaces. They only need to reproduce the namespaces, and don't know that the prefix used is irrelevant to any self-respecting program.

Comment: @TheJuice: in that case, he should admit it, so that we can all ridicule him for having a program that doesn't understand XML namespaces properly. We could then help him fix that. But first step is to admit the problem. :-)

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the nice words about my program with no self respect! Actually the XML file that i need to reproduce is for another application that I don't have any power over or will ever be allowed to manipulate. So I have received a XML specification. And what they need in the XML to be able to read it. So for my point of view I just need to accept their terms, and add all the namespaces above.

Comment: @Niike2: my issue was not with the namespaces, but with the prefixes. You should be able to use any prefix you like, as long as the namespaces are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Completed the question with input from the previous answer. This is just to show you how to get the desired result if anyone searches for this in the future. This is created to be opened in Office Excel. So Linq To XML exported to an .xml file to be able to be opened in Excel easily.

**Goal formatting:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<ss:Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:x2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/excel/2003/xml" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" xmlns:c="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:component:spreadsheet">
  <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" />
  <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" />
  <ss:Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet 1">
    <ss:Table>
      <ss:Row>
        <ss:Cell>
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">name</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">sku</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
      </ss:Row>
      <ss:Row>
        <ss:Cell>
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Suunto Elementum Terra</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
          <ss:Data ss:Type="String">SS014522000</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
      </ss:Row>
    </ss:Table>
  </ss:Worksheet>
</ss:Workbook>
```

**Code to generate the desired XML.**

```
// Linq to XML - Namespaces
XNamespace ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
XNamespace x = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel";
XNamespace x2 = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/excel/2003/xml";
XNamespace ss = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";
XNamespace o = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office";
XNamespace html = "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40";
XNamespace c = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:component:spreadsheet";

// Linq to XML - Document
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", string.Empty),
    new XProcessingInstruction("mso-application", "progid=\"Excel.Sheet\""),
    new XElement(ns + "Workbook",
        new XAttribute("xmlns", ns.NamespaceName),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi.NamespaceName),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "x", x.NamespaceName),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "x2", x2.NamespaceName),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ss", ss.NamespaceName),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "o", o.NamespaceName),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "html", html.NamespaceName),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "c", c.NamespaceName),
        new XElement(o + "OfficeDocumentSettings",
            new XAttribute("xmlns", o.NamespaceName)),
        new XElement(x + "ExcelWorkbook",
            new XAttribute("xmlns", x.NamespaceName)),
        new XElement("Worksheet",
            new XAttribute(ss + "Name", "Sheet 1"),
            new XElement("Table", // 1st Table
                new XElement("Row", // First Row
                    new XElement("Cell", // First Cell on First Row
                        new XElement("Data", new XAttribute(ss + "Type", "String"), "name") // Data in Cell A1
                    ),
                    new XElement("Cell",
                        new XElement("Data", new XAttribute(ss + "Type", "String"), "age") // Data in Cell B1
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
// Loop through a collection. Each iteration is a new row
foreach (Product product in products)
{
    // Linq to XML - Data
    doc.Descendants("Row").First().AddAfterSelf(
        new XElement("Row",
            new XElement("Cell",
                new XElement("Data", new XAttribute(ss + "Type", "String"), product.Name)), // Data in Cell A2
            new XElement("Cell",
                new XElement("Data", new XAttribute(ss + "Type", "String"), product.Age) // Data in Cell B2
            )
        )
    );
}
// Namespace fix. Deletes any empty xmlns="" text in every node.
foreach (XElement e in doc.Root.DescendantsAndSelf())
{ 
    if (e.Name.Namespace == string.Empty) 
    {
        e.Name = ns + e.Name.LocalName;
    } 
}
```

Comment: When I do this I get <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet 1" xmlns=""> - note the blank xmlns - this stops excel from opening it